# Model Arcitecture Flow With Wallet Referral and WalletLog

Tags: python, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

Quest is: **How would I link all three models as My requirements**.

**Requirements:** If user referred to someone `(other User)` he will get some `amount` in his `wallet (Referral Based)` . One `user` can `refer` to many `user`.

As I mentioned above the requirements Criteria... please Do the need full

I have to create three Models as mentioned below given which are linked up with `User` models.

```
1. Wallet
2. Wallet_Log
3. Referral
```

See the model that Created need Suggestion..

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(user, related_name='wallet', unique=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    walletID = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="00000")
    ack = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % self.owner

    @property
    def set_ack(self):
        return self.ack

    @set_ack.setter
    def set_ack(self, bol):
        self.ack = bol

class WalletLog(models.Model):
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(Wallet)
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(user, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()   
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    report = models.CharField(max_length=100)  


    def get_wallet_log(self):
        if(self.wallet):
            return "%s"%(self.wallet.amount)
        else:
            return "Not Available"

    def get_user_from_log(self):
        if(self.user_from):
            return "%s"%(self.user_from.user_first_name)
        else:
            return "Not Available"

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % self.wallet


class OrderReferral(models.Model):

    referrer = models.ForeignKey(user, related_name='referrer')
    referred = models.ForeignKey(user, related_name='referred')
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(Wallet, related_name='order_referred')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField()
    order_active = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s made a referral' % (self.referrer.first_name, self.referrer.last_name)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Order Referral"
```

Comment: Want answer anyone here....   Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes Finally set the `model relationship` in proper way to avoid the unnecessarily `join query` by writing `test case` and `code`.